# in Spring Cloud Config, how does curl client works?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

in my repo, there are three files: `config-client-dev.properties` , `config-client-prod.properties` and `config-client.properties` .

and I use curl like:

```
curl http://localhost:8888/config-client/dev/master
curl http://localhost:8888/config-client/prod/master
curl http://localhost:8888/config-client/default/master
```

the result I got was like:

> {"name":"config-client","profiles":["prod"],"label":"master","version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[]}

Is there any way to get the values inside the properties files?

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#_serving_alternative_formats

Comment: @spencergibb can you explain? don't get it

Comment: /{application}-{profile}.yml
/{label}/{application}-{profile}.yml
/{application}-{profile}.properties
/{label}/{application}-{profile}.properties

Answer (score 4):

Your result

```json
{
   "name":"config-client",
   "profiles":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "label":"master",
   "version":null,
   "state":null,
   "propertySources":[
      
   ]
}
```

it is wrong. You must call

```
curl http://localhost:8888/config-client/dev
curl http://localhost:8888/config-client/prod
curl http://localhost:8888/config-client/default
```

(remove the name of branch `master`)

Let's see an example from reference document: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#_quick_start

[image]